# Drain coolant as much as possible through radiator drain valve?

Tags: ford, coolant, cooling-system, crown-victoria, ford-panther-platform

I want to perform a complete coolant flush on my 08 Crown Victoria. 
I have some 50/50 coolant and I guess the remaining distilled water will over-dilute the antifreeze. Is there a way to drain most of the water out of the cooling system? Will removing thermostat and starting the engine help with draining?

Comment: Do you have access to an airlift or similar tool? We use one to basically vacuum the coolant out. Also, see if your water pump has a drain plug.

Comment: there are often one or more bleeder taps that should be opened. Look at the high points of the cooling system like the top of the thermostat housing.

Comment: @DavidLively I only have basic tools and no wet vacuum. Worst case is I go to auto store and buy some antifreeze concentrate I guess.

Comment: What year is the car?

Comment: @agentp I can see something that looks like a bleeder on the engine block. Gonna check against the manual and see what it is. If I open the tap, will it help get rid of most coolant from the engine?

Comment: @DavidLively 2008 and I suspect no coolant change has ever been performed on this car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of a way to get all the water out. Some engines have drain plugs in the back of the block. My Ford 4.6 does, but they are rusted and hard to get to.

As an alternative, since it is nearly impossible to get all the water out, it is a good idea to use straight coolant and add 60 - 70% coolant to the system after the water flush. This will mix with the water already in the block to give you roughly a 50/50 blend.

[FordTechMakuloco](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCN467fmgLLlk98JddJLL51w) discusses this in his video [How To Perform A Coolant Flush On Your Ford Vehicle](https://youtu.be/RWIXa50R9bo) (around 8:41 mark).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will buy coolant concentrate to mix with water in the engine block.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answers your question satisfactorily, feel free to give it an approving check mark so others will know the question is answered.